# Getting Token expired for all json post requests

Tags: laravel-5, jmeter, token, csrf

I am passing token in all the headers but it only works for login, after that for all requests it says "Token Expired"

Token Setup :

[image]

[image]

Output in Result tree :

[image]

Also when I look at my website, I can see 2 tokens :

```
<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="AqrfjMcG1adWWDlx8YYkYqOCy3Mwp7fRynwut222">


<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="AqrfjMcG1adWWDlx8YYkYqOCy3Mwp7fRynwut222">
```

So I am passing _token for all request headers as above both has same content/value.

I am also not sure about `x-socket-id`, It came be default as I recorded script. is it ok to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My expectation is that you need to extract the token not only from the very first response, you need to keep extracting it from **all subsequent responses**, so move your Regular Expression Extractor to the same level as your HTTP Request samplers are so it will be applied to all the requests according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)

Also be aware that for HTML responses it makes more sense to use [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor), it is not sensitive to markup changes, more powerful and less fragile:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a **HTTP cookie manager** along in the test plan

For each request the token is authenticated when using the CSRF token. Hope this helps!